# Javascript airbnb react-dates showClearDate throwing

Tags: react-datepicker, react-dates

I am trying to get the clear date button appearing on the SingleDatePicker. Looking at the documentation all I have to do is add the showClearDate attribute to the SingleDatePicker. This is how I've implemented it:

```
<SingleDatePicker 
    date={null}
    isOutsideRange={ (date) => {return false} }
    id={detail.name}
    showClearDate={true}
    focused={focused}
    numberOfMonths={ 1 }
    onDateChange={ (date) => { handleDateChange( momentToISO(date) )}}
    onFocusChange={({ focused }) =>{ 
      handleFocusChange(focused) 
      }
    }
  />
```

Evertying works fine if I remove the showClearDate attribute (without showing the button of course) but when I add this attribute in I get an exception "cannot read property onClearDateMouseEnter of undefined"

The following is taken from the react-dates SingleDatePickerInput.jsx showing where the error is occurring.

```
 {showClearDate && (
    <button
      {...css(
        styles.SingleDatePickerInput_clearDate,
        small && styles.SingleDatePickerInput_clearDate__small,
        !customCloseIcon && styles.SingleDatePickerInput_clearDate__default,
        !displayValue && styles.SingleDatePickerInput_clearDate__hide,
      )}
      type="button"
      aria-label={phrases.clearDate}
      disabled={disabled}
      onMouseEnter={this.onClearDateMouseEnter} // here
      onMouseLeave={this.onClearDateMouseLeave} // i imagine here too
      onClick={onClearDate}
    >
      {closeIcon}
    </button>
  )}
```

There is no reference in the documentation to having to supply the function onClearDateMouseEnter function or any other reference to it in code.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. I get the same error "SingleDatePickerInput.js:236 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClearDateMouseEnter' of undefined".

It looks like they fixed it in [17.1.1](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/commit/93c5b989f4eba87f3dafb1a21f7a334ab264e061#diff-83afa0070b64b731151095328b163645). Let's see if this helps, I'll test it soon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated to version 17.1.1. It no longer throws but it doesnt show the clear button.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe one of the breaking changes of 17.0.0 caused this issue? https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1700 (Note: I have not yet updated it myself, just saw that 17.1.1 fixed the initial issue during research).

Comment: For me, 16.2.1 was working, but 16.7 broke it, so I reverted it back.